# IdentityServer3 External Provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I was hoping that someone could provide some context.

My organization is building a native external app.  Our goal is to avoid being directed to the authorization server in any way (customer's requirement, not ours). I understand the benefits of the true redirect flow SSO, etc.

Using redirect flows I was able to use the acr_values attributes to redirect out to the third party provider to obtain a code; but I am still directed back to our identity server for the user to grant permissions to the various requested scopes.

Is there any way around this?  We are using Resource Owner grants for our native login; and this works great.  Likewise the redirect to the third party login is acceptable as well.

The customer doesn't want a user to have to grant permissions to scopes/roles for an app that will remain 100% proprietary.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a product of my limited knowledge of redirect flows.  I was missing the RequireConsent property .... I set this to false and was able to proceed.